# jstree close rest of the branches when opening a branch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using jsTree. If I expand/open a branch, I want the rest of the (opened) branches to get closed/collapsed.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the node open event to look through the tree and close other nodes. I presume you want to keep open the just now expanded node and all its parents.

Like so:

```
$('#tree').on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) {

    var nodesToKeepOpen = [];

        // get all parent nodes to keep open
        $('#'+data.node.id).parents('.jstree-node').each(function() {
           nodesToKeepOpen.push(this.id);
        });

        // add current node to keep open
        nodesToKeepOpen.push( data.node.id );

        // close all other nodes
        $('.jstree-node').each( function() {
            if( nodesToKeepOpen.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ) {
                $("#tree").jstree().close_node(this.id);
            }
        })
})
```

See demo [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/dxm6w9ur/)